# azure powershell can't find resource (vm) by name

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to increase the size of my azure linux VM disk through powershell as the azure portal dashboard can't do it for this VM. I am having trouble getting the VM in the resource group, it can't be found.

Note the resource group and resource name are the same. Is there an alternative way of getting the resource, I have tried by ID but no luck

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName 'BizSpark'
$rgName = 'abc'
$vmName = 'abc'
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName
```

The error am getting is

> Get-AzureRmVM : The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/abc'
>   under resource group 'abc' was not found.

Comment: I am guessing this issue is from the switch from service manager to resource manager

Comment: do you have several subscriptions, check that you selected the proper subscription

Comment: What Azure PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: thanks for your help, please check the comments from @Walter - MSFT

Comment: The term 'Select-AzureRmSubscription' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, it seems that your have multiple subscriptions and your VM is not in your default subscription. So, you need select correct subscriptions. Please refer the following steps:

1.Determine your subscription name and subscription id in Azure Portal.

[image]

2.Change the default subscription.

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "your subscription name"
```

Update:

If your VM is based on classic VM, you need use `Get-AzureVM` to list your VM.

Comment: thanks, but i have one subscription confirmed it in powershell and on my portal account.

Comment: What is your Azure Powershell version? Use the cmdlet`Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`

Comment: Could you get VM information by using `get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName groupname`

Comment: ModuleType : Manifest
Version : 3.4.0
this is the output from that command. As things stand am thinking of backing up the VM, creating a new VM with a bigger disk and importing the backup image.. this is a pain

Comment: This is the latest version. Could you get VM by using `get-azurermvm` without parameter `name`?

Comment: I have run that and it returns nothing. I have tried running with and without the resource group, still nothing. As I had mentioned, I had created these machines in the classic azure portal, could that be the issue? Could attaching an additional disk to the vm bypass this issue? I could then move some of my apps to that new disk?

Comment: Yes, you could not use `get-azurermvm` to list ARM VM, you need use `get-azurevm`

Comment: When I run this command 
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $rgName
It lists the resources on that group (..../Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/abc and its VM ....../Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/abc). My resource group is called 'abc' the domain has name 'abc' and the vm also has name 'abc'

Comment: @ck9g08 According to your log, I think your VM is classic VM, you could not use ARM cmdlet to list it.

Comment: thanks, now am able to list the VMs (3) on subscription using the get-azurevm command. Please assist me on how to access the vm and then update it's disk size. The script I was planning on using will not work because it is based on the resource manager type of syntax e.g Update-AzureRmVm

Comment: thanks for your help, i will check out the link. I can't give a public upvote, my reputation is too low.

Comment: No thanks, the link you recommended worked out. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without specifying the resource group e.g.

```
#Login to your sub
login-azurermaccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName 'BizSpark'
$vms = Get-AzureRmVM
#list all the VMs returned by the above command
$vms
#first VM in the above collection
$vms[0]
#id of first vm
$vms[0].id
```

If that doesn't work, it is worth checking you are running the latest version of the cmdlets as I have encountered some great behaviors that have been fixed by updating.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azureps-cmdlets-docs/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However this returns an empty array for some reason and throws the null exception on access of the array. PS. There is a small typo, it should Get-AzureRmVM

Comment: Thanks have corrected!  If you use get-azurermsubscription does the subscription id tally with that you can see under the portal -> Subscriptions?  As noted in an earlier comment does the fact you need to select a Subscription imply you have access to multiple Subscriptions?  If so do you have sufficient permissions in the BizSpark Subscription?

Comment: Hi all, the issue is not with 2 subscriptions, I have only one subscription..I have also run Get-AzureSubscription | select SubscriptionName and confirmed that.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have the latest version of the PowerShell Cmdlets installed to eliminate the possibility that it is an issue there?  The other option perhaps is the Azure CLI tools?